# How to use Custom Metadata methods in the function?

Tags: apex, custom-metadata

I would like to use
*CustomMetadata_mdt.getall().values()* function to retrieve metadata in apex function. Custom Metadata CustomMetadata_mdt should be the function's parameter. How can I achieve this?

```
public static Map<String, SObject> getCustomMetadataRecords(??? metadata){
   // Do some pre-processing
   List<???> records = metadata.getAll().values();
   // Do some post-processing

   Map<String, SObject> developerNameRecordMap = new Map<String, SObject>();
   for(SObject record: records){
         developerNameRecordMap.put(String.valueOf(record.get('DeveloperName')), 
         record);
    }
   return developerNameRecordMap;   
}
```

I could not anywhere find what's the parent class of the [getAll() method](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_dev_static_accessor.htm&type=5&release=230)

If I search in developer guide, [CustomMetadata Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Metadata_CustomMetadata.htm#apex_Metadata_CustomMetadata_description) does not show `getAll()` method:

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it dynamically. If you would like to retrieve based on a dynamic name, you need to use SOQL.

```
public static Map<String, SObject> getCustomMetadata(String metadataName)
{
    String soql = 'SELECT ... FROM ' + metadataName;
    return new Map<Id, SObject>(Database.query(soql));
}
```

If you want the dynamic query to include all fields, you would need to use describe methods to figure out which you want. Without knowing where you are trying to plug this tool into your system, it is difficult to say, but making it generic likely does not add value here.

Answer (score 1):

As Adrian's answer notes - you won't be able to do this dynamically.

In terms of documentation - it's under the [System Namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_namespace_System.htm) for [Custom Metadata Type Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_custom_metadata_types.htm#test) - it has this mention

> **Usage**
>
> Custom metadata types methods are instance type methods and **are
> called by and operate on a specific instance of a custom metadata
> type.**

The description of `getAll()` also mentions it can only be used on a specific custom metadata type

> Returns a map containing custom metadata records for the specific
> custom metadata type. The map's keys are the IDs of the records and
> the map’s values are the record sObjects.